# Vectorize HumanName library for pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a `full_name` column in a pandas DataFrame which has names of individuals. For example:

```
Full_Name

Saumendra Nayak
Pawan Shinde
Arun Chopra
Neil Anderson
```

I have to separate these names into first, second and last name. I have decided to use the HumanName (*nameparser*) library.

However with my current approach, I have to use a loop to split each and every name in my column into its components.

```
# add blank columns based on unique categories

df["title"] = ""
df["first"] = ""
df["middle"] = ""
df["last"] = ""
df["suffix"] = ""
df["nickname"] = ""

# Split name for each row and save values in dataframe

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.loc[i,7]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).title
    df.loc[i,8]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).first
    df.loc[i,9]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).middle
    df.loc[i,10]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).last
    df.loc[i,11]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).suffix
    df.loc[i,12]=HumanName(df.full_Name.loc[i]).nickname
```

I am somewhat new to Python, and this loop seems like something I would be better off avoiding. Can anyone suggest if the HumanName library can be used in a vectorized way, so that I can avoid setting in a loop like in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try first building a name decomposition function, then zipping the components together before assigning columns.

```
components = ('title', 'first', 'middle', 'last', 'suffix', 'nickname')

def name_decomp(n):
    h_n = HumanName(n)
    return (getattr(h_n, comp) for comp in components)

rslts = list(zip(*df.Full_Name.map(name_decomp)))

for i, comp in enumerate(components):
    df[comp] = rslts[i]
```

---

**Similar demo** (*since I don't have that library*)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(strings=['calgary', 'vancouver', 'toronto']))

>>> df 
     strings
0    calgary
1  vancouver
2    toronto

>>> class Decomp:
        def __init__(self, s):
            self.s = s
            self.first = s[0]
            self.last = s[-1]
            self.len = len(s)

>>> components = ('first', 'last', 'len')

>>> def useless_decomp(s):
        dec_s = Decomp(s)
        return (getattr(dec_s, comp) for comp in components)

>>> rslts = list(zip(*df.strings.map(useless_decomp)))

>>> for i, comp in enumerate(components):
        df[comp] = rslts[i]

>>> df 
     strings first last  len
0    calgary     c    y    7
1  vancouver     v    r    9
2    toronto     t    o    7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I tested your function and it is 300 times faster than loop. Can you suggest any Python tutorial that will help me get rid of loops and adapt more faster methods in Python?

Comment: @Enthusiast You're welcome! There's actually loads of good stuff if you poke through the [Pandas tutorial page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html), I particularly liked Tom Augspurger's [Modern Pandas](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) series. Good luck!